# mongodb find documents with fields with a data doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb document like

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("543d563bde1e58511c264340"),
    ...some fields ...
    "pref" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : 1,
            "value" : 0.56
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I find all the documents where `pref` does not contain an entry with `user_id :1`  ?

Comment: `db.test.find({ "pref.user_id" : { "$ne" : 1 } })`

Comment: @wdberkeley That's correct. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're looking for here. If you want to find all entries where `user_id` has any other value than '1', then you'd want:

`db.collection.find({"pref.user_id": {'$ne': 1}})`

If you're looking for documents where the 'user_id' field doesn't exist at all:

`db.collection.find({"pref.user_id": {'$exists': 0}})`

Keep in mind, though the behavior of both of these queries on a nested array. What you're actually going to get is all the documents where **any** of the objects in the 'pref' array matches the specified condition.